# How to delete all records from a table without the selected statement in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT Panel_ID,Delivery_Date 
FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(delivery_date))
       FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY b
       WHERE a.Delivery_Date<=b.Delivery_Date
       AND a.Panel_ID=b.Panel_ID
) < 3 
ORDER BY Panel_ID,Delivery_Date DESC
```

Here I am selecting the latest two dates for each panel ID from a history table.
I want to delete all info without deleting this selected statement info.
How can I do this?

Comment: Can I use cursor to complete this?
If I can u suggest how can Ido that?

Comment: From which table do you actually want to delete records?

Comment: SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY

Comment: What is the primary key column of this table?

Comment: No primary key here

Comment: Is there an implicit composite key?  We need some way of uniquely identifying records in the table from which you want to delete.

Comment: Here I have many dates for a single panel.I just want to delete all the info except two latest dates info. Note that the table has 4 attributes without panel_id and Delivery_date.I want to keep these attributes info regarding that two dates also :)

Comment: Please alter your Question's tags to indicate *which* of `MySQL`, `SQL-Server` and `Oracle` you are using

Comment: "I want to keep these attributes info regarding that two dates " Can you expand on this requirement and provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: @toonice, I removed them all. OP can put one of them back, the tag for the dbms actually used.

Comment: jarlh, I have added one for `sql-server`, based on the Question's title.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
DELETE SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY
FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Panel_ID ORDER BY Delivery_Date DESC ) AS recordNumber,
                    Panel_ID AS Panel_ID,
                    Delivery_Date AS Delivery_Date
             FROM ( SELECT Panel_ID AS Panel_ID,
                           Delivery_Date AS Delivery_Date
                    FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY
                    GROUP BY Panel_ID,
                             Delivery_Date
                  ) AS uniquePanel_IDDelivery_Date
           ) AS recordsToKeepFinder ON SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY.Panel_ID <> recordsToKeepFinder.Panel_ID
                                   AND SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY.Delivery_Date <> recordsToKeepFinder.Delivery_Date
                                   AND recordNumber > 2;
```

This statement takes the list generated by your supplied statement (sans the ordering, which is not useful here), and performs an `INNER JOIN` with `SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY` in such a way that every record from `SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY` that does *not* have a matching `Panel_ID` and `Delivery_Date` is retained in the `SELECT` statement's results, and every record that *does* match is omitted.  Every record retained by the `SELECT` statement is then deleted from `SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Can you tell me anything more about the error, such as the full text of the error message?

Comment: I need to contain all info in the table.just to delete all records except this two latest date for each panel_id records

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '*'
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'

Comment: I have updated my Answer.  If this produces an error message, then please reply with the full text of the error message.

Comment: Please alter your Question's tags to indicate which of `MySQL` and `Oracle` you are using.

Comment: Update performed.  Please advise me of the results.

Comment: Receiving error that the multi-part identifier SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY.Panel_ID,SalesFact_Final_Hi‌​story_bk_04MAY.Delivery_date couldn't be bound

Comment: Update posted.  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's the Solution:** Can you please try with this:

```
DELETE a
FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(delivery_date))
        FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY b
        WHERE a.Delivery_Date<=b.Delivery_Date
        AND a.Panel_ID=b.Panel_ID
) >= 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this code 

DELETE FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY WHERE Panel_ID NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT Panel_ID
FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY a
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(delivery_date))
FROM SalesFact_Final_History_bk_04MAY b
WHERE a.Delivery_Date<=b.Delivery_Date
AND a.Panel_ID=b.Panel_ID
) < 3 
ORDER BY PANEL_ID,DELIVERY_DATE DESC
)
```

Comment: The list that `Panel_ID` is compared to in your first `WHERE` clause needs to return one field, not two.  `SQL-Server` can not safely determine which field is the subject of the comparison.  Also, please make use of indenting to identify which level of the statement a piece of code belongs to.